# Preciso alterar somente a metade dos registros de uma tabela MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Fiz esta *procedure* no MySQL para alterar um registro somente da metade da tabela mas ele produz um erro inexplicável:

Ao que parece a encrenca esta no `LIMIT` que se recusa a aceitar uma variável.

No SQLServer eu usava o `TOP (50) PERCENT` resolvia o problema, mas no MySQL não encontro solução. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
BEGIN
DECLARE CodigoNovaLista INT;
DECLARE QuantidadeTotal INT;
DECLARE QuantidadeListaNova INT;
DECLARE QuantidadeListaAtual INT;

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION ROLLBACK;
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING ROLLBACK;

START TRANSACTION;
SELECT QuantidadeTotal = TotalEmails FROM tabelalistas WHERE IDLista = @IDListaAtual;

SET QuantidadeListaAtual =  QuantidadeTotal /2;
SET QuantidadeListaNova = QuantidadeTotal - QuantidadeListaAtual;

INSERT INTO tabelalistas (Nome, IDCliente) VALUES(@NovoNome, @IDCliente); 
SELECT CodigoNovaLista = LAST_INSERT_ID();

UPDATE tabelaemailsimportados SET IDLista=CodigoNovaLista WHERE IDLista = @IDListaAtual LIMIT QuantidadeListaNova;

UPDATE tabelalistas SET TotalEmails=QuantidadeListaAtual WHERE IDLista = @IDListaAtual ;
UPDATE tabelalistas SET TotalEmails=QuantidadeListaNova WHERE IDLista = CodigoNovaLista ;

COMMIT;
END
```

Comment: parece muito simples mas não entendi o motivo de "alterar somente a metade dos registros de uma tabela". No código acima tem um trecho com INSERT e depois vem uns updates estranhos que parece trocar o id lista com o novo.. Mas não entendi o sentido disso.. aliás, não entendi nada. hehehe

Comment: Pode criar um [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) demonstrando o problema? Não há nada errado em usar `LIMIT` no `UPDATE` (veja [o manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)). Deve ser algum problema de sintaxe, porem fica difícil de testar sem um exemplo.

Comment: Outra coisa, se alterar aproximadamente 50% dos registros e em qualquer ordem resolve o problema, existe [um método mais fácil](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11087059/mysql-how-do-i-update-50-of-the-rows-randomly-selected) `UPDATE tabelaemailsimportados SET IDLista=CodigoNovaLista WHERE IDLista = @IDListaAtual AND RAND() < 0.5`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa é montar a query numa variável texto e executá-la de forma dinâmica com o comando [`EXECUTE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-statements.html).

Exemplo:

```sql
EXECUTE 'UPDATE tabelaemailsimportados ' ||
    ' SET IDLista=CodigoNovaLista WHERE IDLista = ' || 
    to_char(@IDListaAtual, '9') || 
    ' LIMIT ' || to_char(@QuantidadeListaNova, '9')
```